# Having trouble injecting a style using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add a style to an element but dont have the full element name.
I have used document.querySelector to find the element and save its id to a variable named elID, this is what i have so far.

```
var elID = document.querySelector('[id^="slide-bg-"]').id;
console.log(elID);
document.getElementById(elID).setAttribute("style", "fill-opacity: 0;");
```

However it is not setting the attribute, instead i get the error "actionator::exeJavaScript - elID.setAttribute is not a function"

[html of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOHd1.png)

Comment: you need to pass a string to querySelector. Youre probably missing some ' ' ..., and querySelector should already returned the wanted object, wrapping it in a getElementById call isnt working.

Comment: with pure vanilla js?

Comment: @ivan questions just tagged with js are always pure js questions.

Comment: `"style,"fill-opacity: 0;"`  - something is missing here...

Comment: Im sorry but this question contains so many obvious mistakes that its kind of unanswerable :/

Comment: `var elID = document.querySelector([id^="side-bg-"]).getAttribute("id")` it return id..

Comment: @Mainstreeem back to the book.

Comment: sorry if my low experience level shines through... all i really want to do is add the fill-opacity 0 to the object. Didnt think it would be this convoluted.

Comment: can you post what "console.log(elID);" is output

Comment: its outputting exactly what i think it should slide-bg-6ZEEBMiB1Jo 
the string after the second - will be different which is why i am trying to get the current id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var elID = document.querySelector('[id^="slide=bg-"]').getAttribute("id");
document.getElementById(elID).setAttribute("style", "fill-opacity: 0;");
```

This seems to do this trick, thank all for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, argument to `querySelector` should be a String `""`, not an Array `[]`.
`querySelector` returns the first matched element not the *ID*. So `elID` will reference an `Element` not an ID String. Also, you're missing quotes around `"style"`

```
 var elID = document.querySelector('[id^="slide-bg-"]')
 elID.setAttribute("style", "fill-opacity: 0;");
```

also, instead of using `elID.setAttribute("style", "fill-opacity: 0;");` go for:

```
elID.style.fillOpacity = 0;
```